# ASP.Net Membership principalpermission issues

Tags: asp.net, membership, principalpermission

I'm running into an issue with the `PrinciplePermissionAttribute` causing exceptions. Any pages where I have the attribute on the `Load` method throw an exception immediately after initial login.

```
<PrincipalePermission(SecurityAction.Demand, role:="Level1")> _
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub
```

This throws the exception `Request for principal permission failed`.

If I remove this the page loads fine and I can navigate to another page that does have this same attribute and it works flawlessly. Also if I use the Membership systems `Roles.IsUserInRole()` function I do not have an issue.

I have noticed that after initial login that my `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is of type `GenericPrincipal` and not the `RolePrincipal`. Subsequent requests show the correct type in place of the generic. I tried to force this in the `Global.asax` file in the `PostAuthenticate` event but asp.net seems to be setting the `GenericPrincipal` after this happens.

Any ideas on how to fix this behavior or am I stuck using the `Roles.IsUserInRole()` method?

**UPDATE**
After finding some explanation into whats happening in the pipeline [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-vb) I can see why changing it in the `Global.asax` didn't help. I had a prototype project from earlier that I tested this with and I could not reproduce it there. I do wonder if it has anything to do with the project type. The prototype is a Web Site project and the problematic one is a Web Application project.

I do think its odd that the `GenericPrincipal` is changed to the `RolePrincipal` but only after the initial request has processed. So its hard to say that its not working its like it just doesn't happen before my 'Page_Load' executes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Forms authentication...

PrincipalPermission attribute checks Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Roles.IsUserInRole() checks HttpContext.Current.User. So if they are different you can correct this in Global.asax file at Application_AuthenticateRequest event.